# token contract - error in Transaction

Tags: contract-development, transactions

I did ethereum token for test in ropsten network, when i try buy some token, there is error in transaction: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x14b75395c6db502172dc7e6fddda0fc4c319e4e9cbdbfa39ae4c16c68c99367f

Contract source is here - https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x944d80528b1669119bfc635aea0f088f1697dc63#code

**How fix it?**

Answer (score 2):

You sent 0.2 ether to this contract, but the contract code says:

```
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Don't accept ETH
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
function () public payable {
    revert();
}
```

The transaction was reverted because the contract does not accept ether.

Comment: thanks, but its not solve problem, i get same error in new contract without that part of code: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x13ee9c9f97522faf8ba34ffd407c13996ef59d91b3614aabf3bc5be2adac39d7

Comment: The default for a contract is to not accept ether. If you want the contract to accept ether, you need to write a payable function that doesn't revert. E.g. `function () public payable { /* do something here */ }`

Comment: can you send me what exactly add to code? I dont know. What exactly write to "do something here" to make it works?

Comment: I don't know what you want your code to do. You're the one writing it.

Comment: allright, i did new smart contract here: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x2e52b4d709196011bfcbe9f34838d01cd92ee2ff#code I fixed here failed transactions. But what i need to do - when i send some ethereum, i want get some token. And how you can see, when i sent 0.2 ethereum i didnt get any token and tokens still have only owner.

Comment: I believe this question has been answered.